# Does salesforce Apex has auto populate function

Tags: apex, jquery

I am trying to have billing address populate in the shipping  address if its same. does apex has anything native that does this for you? or should I search for jquery Auto populate functions?

Comment: You could do it via the controller but quicker and easier to just use jQuery

Comment: alright, Ill search and see if I can find jquery , thank you @Eric

Comment: Depending on your requirement, you could also use a workflow to do this if a box is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric said you can do it easily with jQuery as below. This example assumes that you have a checkbox to let users allow autofill. Hope this will be a good starting point.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#check-address').click(function(){
        if($('#check-address').attr('checked')){
            $('#address-field1').val($('#address-field').val());
            $('#city-field1').val($('#city-field').val());
            $('#zip-field1').val($('#zip-field').val());
            var state = $('#state-field option:selected').val();
            $('#state-field1 option[value=' + state + ']').attr('selected','selected');
        } else { 
            //Clear on uncheck
            $('#address-field1').val("");
            $('#city-field1').val("");
            $('#zip-field1').val("");
            $('#state-field1 option[value=Nothing]').attr('selected','selected');
        };

    });
});
</script>
```